# Switch case for attr values

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, switch-statement

I'm trying to apply a data attribute to an input when a certain radio button is selected. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="continue" name="continue" class="continuebtn" data-animation="1"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
switch(checkvalue) {
            case 'nospace':
                $("input").attr("data-goto", "5");
                break;

            case 'disarray':
                $("input").attr("data-goto", "6");
                break;

            case 'maintain':
                $("input").attr("data-goto", "7");
                break;
            }
            /*return false;*/
```

My problem is that when I hit the back button and choose a new radio button, it won't switch out the data-goto value. I've tried a million different things and can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you enter in the switch ?

Comment: Hit the back button? Coming back to the page with this n it, or going back from this page?

Comment: It works the first time around. It will add the attribute/value, and go to page 5 (first case). If I hit the back button on page 5 to go back to the radio buttons, and choose a new radio button, it will only go to page 5 - not 6 or 7. I somehow need to remove / replace the current value with the new one.

Comment: Where are you getting "checkvalue" from? Checkbox, text, dropdown?

Comment: I just realized that I have return false at the end, which is causing the problem. Now I have to figure out how to stop the page from refreshing on submit without the return false.

Comment: Does it need to be a type="submit"? If you don't want a refresh, why not use type="button"?

Comment: Switched it to a button and now I'm back to square one, with or without the return false.